# Added dependency in Gradle, Liferay says "Unresolved requirement: Import-Package"

Tags: gradle, liferay, liferay-7, bnd

I wrote a Liferay module and deployed it successfully.

Then I added this line in `build.gradle`'s `dependencies` section:

```
compileOnly group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
```

After running `./gradlew eclipse` I can use the library with no problem in Eclipse. But deployment fails:

```
12:29:35,454 WARN  [fileinstall-/home/nico/liferay/osgi/modules][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:103] Error while starting bundle: file:/home/nico/liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-sp3/osgi/modules/de.nico.mymodule-1.0.0.jar 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: de.nico.mymodule [1085]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="4.5.3"_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

I have no idea why it is looking for `org.apache.http` and not `org.apache.httpcomponents`.

Here is my `bnd.bnd`:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.nico.mymodule
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
```

How to investigate this problem?
I don't want to download/add the JAR manually.

Answer (score 3):

In your bnd.bnd

add this code ..

```
Import-Package:\
    !org.apache.*,\
    \
    *
```

Answer (score 2):

the further investigations will start at the exception messsage. It says that the following requirement is not present at RUNTIME:

> Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="4.5.3"

I'm assuming that it's one of the following:

- you didn't deploy the httpcomponents (or a version you need .. see [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)) libraries to Liferay (as compile works, while deployment fails)
- httpcomponents might not be packaged as OSGi bundles. In that case you'll have to decide how to make the code available. Good starting points for more information are [the official docs](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module) (thanks Andrea, promoting this from the comments) and [David Nebinger's blog article](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies)

*How* you add those dependencies to Liferay's runtime is up to you. If the dependencies are OSGi bundles, you can download&deploy them directly. If they're no OSGi bundles, follow one of the techniques described in the linked articles.

Comment: There're also some official docs about it: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module

Comment: @AndreaDiGiorgi: I tried what is described at that page and got `Could not find method compileInclude() for arguments [{group=org.apache.httpcomponents, name=httpclient, version=4.5.3}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler`

Comment: @Olaf Indeed I did not "deploy httpcomponents to Liferay", I was thinking Gradle would include the right things into my module. I have found https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi , do you suggest I manually download it and its many dependencies, and put them all into Liferay's deploy/ folder?

Comment: If you are in a Liferay Workspace, you need at least version 1.2.3. Instead, if you're using `com.liferay.gradle.plugins` directly, you need at least version 3.1.0. Just in case, you should try to update your Gradle plugins to the latest version.

Comment: @AndreaDiGiorgi: I get this error with `com.liferay.gradle.plugins` set to `3.2.29`.